# Java Stack Application

Tags: java, stack

I have a Java problem that involves reading a text file and check that it has properly balanced curly braces, square brackets, and parentheses - '{', '}', '[', ']', '(', and ')'.

I have no problem reading the file, but now I am supposed to use a data member called DelimPos to hold onto the line and character whenever I find one of the delimiters while reading the file and then put it in a `Stack<DelimPos>`.  I am then supposed to go through the stack and print out any errors (ie. unbalanced delimiters like '{ [ }').

Whenever I try to make a new `DelimPos d = new DelimPos(x, y)` in the main method, it gave me this error

> No enclosing instance of type BalancedApp is accessible. Must qualify
>   the allocation with an enclosing instance of type BalancedApp (e.g.
>   x.new A() where x is an instance of BalancedApp).

I am unsure what the best way would be to use DelimPos in this program.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Stack;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;



public class BalancedApp {

Stack<DelimPos> s = new Stack<DelimPos>();
public class DelimPos
{
    private int linecnt;
    private char ch;

    public DelimPos(int lineCount, char character)
    {
        linecnt = lineCount;
        ch = character;

    }

    public char getCharacter()
    {
        return  ch;
    }

    public int getLineCount()
    {
        return linecnt;
    }

}





public static void main(String args[]) {


    int lineCount = 1;


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a file name: ");
    String inputFile = sc.next();


    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        int text;

        System.out.print(lineCount + ". ");


        while((text = reader.read()) != -1)
        {
            char character = (char) text;
            if(character == '\n')
            {
                System.out.print(character);
                lineCount++;
                System.out.print(lineCount + ". ");

            }
            else System.out.print(character);

            DelimPos d = new DelimPos(lineCount, character);

        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
    }


}


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've defined `DelimPos` and main inside the class `BalancedApp`, so as the error says, you need an instance of `BalancedApp` to instantiate a `DelimPos`. There is a better explanation of inner classes [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Looking at the code, though, I don't think you need `BalancedApp` at all.  I would remove it and put your main inside `DelimPos` and your stack inside main.  Something like this:

```
import java.util.Stack;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class DelimPos
{
private int linecnt;
private char ch;

public DelimPos(int lineCount, char character)
{
    linecnt = lineCount;
    ch = character;

}

public char getCharacter()
{
    return  ch;
}

public int getLineCount()
{
    return linecnt;
}




public static void main(String args[]) {
    Stack<DelimPos> s = new Stack<DelimPos>();


    int lineCount = 1;


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a file name: ");
    String inputFile = sc.next();


    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        int text;

        System.out.print(lineCount + ". ");


        while((text = reader.read()) != -1)
        {
            char character = (char) text;
            if(character == '\n')
            {
                System.out.print(character);
                lineCount++;
                System.out.print(lineCount + ". ");

            }
            else System.out.print(character);

            DelimPos d = new DelimPos(lineCount, character);

        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
    }


}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you should define the class as static.

```
public static class DelimPos
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
new BalancedApp.DelimPos(lineCount, character);
```

But I would suggest you to use a seperate implementation of data type instead of using it as a inner class.

Comment: This should be `new BalancedApp().new DelimPos(lineCount, character);`